# Number of ways of writing the integer interval $[1..N]$ as a union of non-overlapping subintervals $[i..j],\,i \le j$

Tags: combinatorics

Consider splitting an integer interval $[1..N]$ into non-overlapping subintervals $[i_k..j_k],\,i_k \le j_k$, i.e.
$$
[1..N] = \bigcup_{k=1}^{K} \, [i_k..j_k] \quad i_1 =1, i_{k+1} = j_{k}+1, j_K=N
$$
How many ways can this be done?

Example: $[1,2,3]$: The set of possibilities is $\{[1]\cup[2]\cup[3],[1]\cup[2,3],[1,2]\cup[3],[1,2,3] \}$ for a total of $4$.

This question is related to [Splitting the set $A=\{1,2,...,n\}$ into at most $m$ non-empty disjoint subsets, whose union is $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3778599/splitting-the-set-a-1-2-n-into-at-most-m-non-empty-disjoint-subsets), but differs in that here the subsets must consist of contiguous numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wanted number is
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{2^{N-1}}
\end{align*}
We can identify each of the intervals with the left-most value as in the case $N=3$:
\begin{align*}
\{[\color{blue}{1}]\cup[\color{blue}{2}]\cup[\color{blue}{3}],[\color{blue}{1}]\cup[\color{blue}{2},3],[\color{blue}{1},2]\cup[\color{blue}{3}],[\color{blue}{1},2,3] \}\qquad\longleftrightarrow\qquad (1,2,3),(1,2),(1,3),(1)
\end{align*}

> We can write this number as sum
> \begin{align*}\color{blue}{\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{1=i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_j\leq N}1}&=\sum_{j=1}^{N}\binom{N-1}{j-1}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}{j}\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=2^{N-1}}
> \end{align*}
> according to the claim.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we note that $j_1=1$ since we always start with $1$. $\binom{N-1}{j-1}$ is the number of $j-1$-tuples $\left(i_2,i_3,\ldots,i_{j}\right)$ between $2$ and $N$.
- In (2) we shift the index by one to start with $j=0$ and apply the binomial theorem.

Comment: Is this a one-off (very cool) insight, or is the same idea useful in other cases as well?

Comment: @BeMuSeD: This is a useful counting technique. Another example is given *[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2844037/nested-summation-intuition/2844081#2844081)*.

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways is $2^{n-1}$. Imagine $n$ objects in a row, numbered $1$ to $n$ from left to right. There are $n-1$ gaps between adjacent objects. In each gap, you can either place a barrier, or not. You can make these $n-1$ binary choices is $2^{n-1}$ ways. The placement of the barriers uniquely determines a partition of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ into intervals.

Comment: I appreciate your combinatorial answers. (+1)